# How to run an EXE file compiled from a F# source on the Mac Terminal?

Tags: command-line, f#

I have a hello world program in F#.

```
open System

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    printfn "Hello World from F#!"
    0 // return an integer exit code%
```

On an Mac OS, I can compile it with "fsharpc", which generates two files

```
FSharp.Core.dll hello.exe
```

The EXE file certainly looks strange on a Mac. But how can I execute it from the command line, without using a project structure (because it seems an overkill) like what is explained here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/languages/fsharp-hello-world-tutorial/create

Actually if I run "dotnet hello.exe", I get this error:

> A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.dylib'
> required to execute the application was not found in
> '/Users/zell/hello/'. Failed to run as a self-contained app. If this
> should be a framework-dependent app, add the
> /Users/zell/hello/hello.runtimeconfig.json file specifying the
> appropriate framework.

Comment: Have you tried `dotnet hello.exe`?

Comment: You can also build it to be a self-contained exe and trim it to reduce size. `dotnet publish -r win-x86 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:PublishTrimmed=true 
` for windows, and replace win-x86 with `osx-x64` (I think).

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Thanks! But that one I already tried. See my updated question :-)

Comment: you shouldn't compile it with fsharpc, but compile it with the dotnet CLI tool. Alternatively, as it appears to be a full framework app, use mono hello.exe to run it.

Comment: @s952163 Thanks. How to compile it with the dotnet CLI tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create and build/run F# apps like so:

```
dotnet new console -lang F# -o SomeDirectory && cd SomeDirectory
dotnet run
```

Building it without running is:

```
dotnet build
```

You can see a reference for all commands here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet

You appear to have Mono installed, which is where `fsharpc` comes from. I wouldn't recommend using that unless you are doing mobile development with Xamarin, which currently requires Mono.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But what if I already have some f# files to run. The command you showed above works with a program called Program.fs without problem but my files are called file1.fs, file2.fs, etc, for example. Is there a way to just compile and run a program like one would use gcc ?

Comment: In .NET you add them to the project file (`.fsproj`) in their dependency order. Then it's just `dotnet build`/`dotnet run`/etc.

Answer (score 0):

By trial and error, I found to run my new `.exe` file, I needed a `.runtimeconfig.json` file in the same folder with same without-the-extension-name, i.e. `hello.runtimeconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "net5.0",
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
      "version": "5.0.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Then `dotnet hello.exe` will work.